# Add an onchange event listener to an html input field

Tags: javascript

I would like to add an `onchange` event to those input fields without jquery:

```
<input type="text" id="cbid.wizard.1._latitude">
<input type="text" id="cbid.wizard.1._longitude">
```

I can already call the object with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.getElementById('cbid.wizard.1._latitude').id);
</script>
```

In the end, I want to add this behaviour, that if you enter a pair of coordinates into the first input, I will spread the pair over the two input fields?

How do I add an `onchange` event with javascript?

Comment: `document.getElementById('cbid.wizard.1._latitude').addEventListener('change',function() { <stuff here> },false);` should work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ummm, attach an event handler for the 'change' event?

**pure JS**

```
document.getElementById('element_id').onchange = function() {
  // your logic
};

// or

document.getElementById('element_id').addEventListener(
  'change',
  callbackFunction,
  false
);
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#element_id').change(function() {
  // your logic
});
```

## Note

Note, that `change` event on the text field will be fired after the `blur` event. It's possible that your looking for `keypress` event's or something like that.

Comment: Basically he's asking for a solution `without jquery`

Comment: But its nivce to have the jQuery equivalent too

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('cbid.wizard.1._latitude').onchange = function(){
   //do something
}
```

[GlobalEventHandlers.onchange docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onchange)

or

```
document.getElementById('cbid.wizard.1._latitude').addEventListener("change", function(){
    //do something
});
```

[EventTarget.addEventListener docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Comment: Don't I need the `window.onload`?

Comment: You should use `window.onload`.

Comment: addEventListener("change", function(){...}); seems to work for the last element in the document if used in the same page how can I solve this. I have three sets of forms on the same page but the change event only affects the one I put last.

Answer (score 3):

use `addEventListener` in your `window.onload`

```
    window.onload=function(){    
document.getElementById('cbid.wizard.1._latitude').addEventListener("change", function(){
            //do something
        });
    };
```

[**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="cbid.wizard.1._latitude">
    <input type="text" id="cbid.wizard.1._longitude">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var txt1 = document.getElementById('cbid.wizard.1._latitude');
        txt1.addEventListener('change', function () { alert('a'); }, false);
    </script>
</body>
```