# How to display text typed into input box immediately after being typed

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

What i'm trying to do is to display text immediately i type them into an input box,so far my javascript function doesn't even work at all,i just need the function to show when a text is typed into or erased in the text boxes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="output-box">
   <P class="Output-text"></P>
   <P class="Output-text2"></P> 
</div>

<div class="forms">
    <form action="POST">
        <label class="label" for="name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" onchange="GetAndDisplayInput()">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label class="label" for="name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id=" last-name" name="name" onchange="GetAndDisplayInput()">
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function GetAndDisplayInput(){
    var inputFirstName= document.getElementById("name").value;
    var inputLastName= document.getElementById("last-name").value;
    document.getElementsByClassName("Output-text").innerHTML = inputFirstName;
    document.getElementsByClassName("Output-text2").innerHTML = outputFirstName;
}
</script>
</body>








</html>
```

Comment: try an "onchange" eventlistener. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865177/add-an-onchange-event-listener-to-an-html-input-field

Comment: @Strella The OP already tried this.

Comment: Tried oninput too but didn't work

Comment: You should also use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` if you don't want the input contents to be interpeted as HTML

Comment: i see the problem is maybe  document.getElementsByClassName("Output-text").innerHTML cause it gives an array.

Answer (score 2):

Try use the `oninput` event listener instead of `onchange`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput

This will fire immediately after every change, as opposed to every time the element is blurred (unfocused / clicked away).

**Example**

```js
function display() {
  document.querySelector("p").innerText = document.querySelector("input").value;
}
```

```html
<input oninput="display();" placeholder="Type in some text">
<p></p>
```

Comment: @HakeemBalogun See my example, it's working for me.